# Asymptotic expected runtime of Randomized Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, randomized-algorithms, average-case

I am analyzing the asymptotic runtime of a randomized algorithm in expectation. The algorithm has the following properties:

- Given input size $n$, with probability $3/4$ it moves on to solve an instance of size $n-1$
- With probability $1/8$ it moves on to solve an instance of size $n-2$
- With probability $1/16$ it moves on to solve an instance of size $n-3$
- With probability $1/2^i$ it moves on to solve an instance of size $n-i$
- Each instance pays a cost of $O(n)$, where $n$ is the input size of that instance

Over expectation, the runtime can be defined recursively as follows:

$T(n) = O(n) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} (\dfrac{1}{2^{n-i+1}} T(i)) + \frac{1}{2}T(i-1)$

$T(0) = O(1)$

I have calculated that the expected number of "jumps" at each stage is $\leq 1$. I did this by showing $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{i}{2^{i+1}}= 1$ by using telescoping and geometric series. However, since the complexity at each stage diminishes as $n$ gets smaller, although this hints the runtime is $O(n^2)$, it does not prove it. Anyone have any ideas to prove a runtime for the less relaxed version?

EDIT: Slight gap in my formulation. The "$3/4$" probability for moving onto an instance of size $n-1$ should actually be larger than $3/4$ since the probabilities $1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ...$ only go on till $1/2^{n+1}$. If no jumps were made, the algorithm deterministically moves on to an instance of size $n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, it is easy to prove by induction that the overall runtime is $O(n^2)$. If we don't have any more information, that's (almost) all we can deduce. For example, suppose that at each instance we pay a cost of $O(1)$. The running time will then be $O(n)$. In order to make progress, we have to assume that at each instance we pay a cost of $\Theta(n)$. In that case, we can argue as follows:

1. Since each "jump" is $O(1)$, it takes $\Omega(n)$ steps (on average) to reach $n/2$.
2. At each of these $\Omega(n)$ steps, we pay a cost of $\Omega(n)$.
3. Hence the total expected cost is $\Omega(n^2)$.

This is not a rigorous argument, but it can be turned into one if you're careful enough.

Comment: My concern is $O(n^2)$ may not be a tight bound. Although it is expected we only make one jump, the payoffs are higher if we were to make a larger jump. I agree with your analysis if for each instance we pay a cost of $O(1)$, but shouldn't there be a way to mathematically show the expected payoff with $O(n)$ per instance still boils down to an $O(n^2)$ algorithm? Without just assuming $\Theta(original\ problem\ size)$ at each step?

Comment: I can't follow what you're saying. It is easy to give an $O(n^2)$ upper bound unconditionally. If you don't know anything more on the cost of each step, the best lower bound you can prove is $\Omega(n)$; indeed, if the cost at each step is $O(1)$, then the running time is $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: My point is even though you expect to only progress one step each time, if you progress, say, all the way to the end, the next iteration has $O(1)$ runtime, since $n$ at the last iteration is $1$. So you can't make the argument by first saying you make $O(n)$ steps and then saying each step is $O(n)$ time. You must solve the recurrence, which gives a lower time complexity if you make bigger steps.

Comment: Right, if you get lucky the algorithm will terminate in $O(n)$. But the expected running time is $\Omega(n^2)$ (assuming the cost at each step is $\Omega(n)$). Even more is true: with high probability the running time is $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: I'm not positive I fully understand, but I'll mark this as accepted, thanks for the insight.